# How to trigger typing animation when a person scrolls beyond a certain point in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have written a code in jquery in which text is typed out when an user scrolls beyond a certain point.  However if the user stops to scroll, the animation is stopped even if its incomplete. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > $('.sec1').offset().top - 100) {
        set();
    }
});

function set() {
    heading1 = 'Gaming Redefined.'
    type(); 
}

function type() {
    $('.heading1').html(heading1.substr(0,len++));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool plugin called typed.js i highly recommend: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

using that plugin you can do something like this:

```js
var typing = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10 && typing == false) {
    typing = true;
    typeIt("This is some funky typed text.");
  }
});

function typeIt(text) {
  $("#typed_output").typed({
    strings: [text],
    typeSpeed: 25,
    startDelay: 400,
    showCursor: false,
    // backDelay: 750, // pause before backspacing
    loop: false, // loop on or off (true or false)
    loopCount: false, // number of loops, false = infinite
    callback: function() {}
      // call function after typing is done. You can use this to set the typing variable to false if you wanted so that your text types again.
      // callback: function(){typing = false; } 
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  background: #333;
}
#typed_output {
  padding: 200px 0 100px 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1 id="typed_output"></h1>
</div>
```